# Add dynamic Parameter to Javascript Array Object by condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add the `parameter` to the `array object url` depends on some function value.

Here is what I have tried so far with no luck.

```
var change_lookup_number = function() {
  var type = document.getElementById('type_number').value;
  if (type == 1) {
    //url should be "/hello/lookup/modelname.js?columns[column_id]=1"
  } else if (type == 2) {
    //url should be "/hello/lookup/modelname.js?columns[column_id]=2"
  } else {
    //url should be "/hello/lookup/modelname.js?columns[column_id]=6"
  }
};

change_lookup_number();

var sections = [
  {
    url: "",
  }
]

(function(){
  $.each(pcdfs, function(i, section) {
   console.log(section.url); // It's empty, I want to change this section.url
  }
})();
```

Thanks

Comment: `return "/hello/lookup/modelname.js?columns[column_id]=" + type==1 ? 1 : 2`

Comment: Thanks @olegv.volkov, Is it on the change_lookup_number function?

Comment: Can you add this to an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Define sections array before accessing it inside your function.

var sections = [
      {
        url: ""
      }
    ];
var change_lookup_number = function() {
      var type = document.getElementById('type_number').value;
      if (type == 1) {
        sections[0].url = "/hello/lookup/modelname.js?columns[column_id]=1"
      } else {
        sections[0].url = "/hello/lookup/modelname.js?columns[column_id]=2"
      }
    };

change_lookup_number();
```

Comment: Thanks Darshan, Is there a way to change the sections variable rather than setting the url in the function?

Comment: what's the final result are you expecting

Comment: The Problem is another function below calling the sections variable and the sections does not change at all. Its still empty.

Comment: which function updates sections. is it change_lookup_number ?

Comment: Like I have another function called catagories(); This function calling that sections

Comment: It's not clear what's you are doing. can you post the complete code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105822/discussion-between-darshan-and-sri).

Comment: move "sections" variable declaration to the top (above change_lookup_number function)